# Javascript. How can I access a variable outside of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm trying to create a simple application that generates a random question with an onclick, and will generate a solution to said question with a different onclick.  I've been able to create the random question function simple enough, but what I'm having trouble with is the solution part.  Essentially I cant access the variables produced from the "generate question" function.

The following function generates a random question: "Convert 10mg/mL to mcg/mL"

```
const arr = ['mg/mL', 'mcg/mL', 'mg/L'];

function genConversion () {
  function clearBox(elementID){ //this resets the question
      document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
  }

  clearBox('output');

  function shuffle(a) { 
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
  }

   function randomNum() {
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
    return number
  }

  var num = randomNum()

  shuffle(arr);

  output.innerHTML += "Convert " + num + ' ' + arr[0] + ' to ' + arr[1]

}
```

Now, when I try to create a function that will solve the generated problem (the actual logic will come once I can figure out how to access the question variables), I cant seem to access variable 'num'.  Interestingly, I am able to access the random array element arr[0].

```
function solveProb() {
  console.log(arr[0]);
  console.log(num);
}
```

Im sure this has something to do with scope that Im having trouble with, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `arr` is global, `num` is not.  Either return `num` and put it into scope or make `num` global like `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the `num` variable outside, then assign to it inside `genConversion`, just like how the `arr` variable is declared outside:

```js
const arr = ['mg/mL', 'mcg/mL', 'mg/L'];
let num;

function genConversion () {
  function clearBox(elementID){ //this resets the question
      document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
  }

  clearBox('output');

  function shuffle(a) { 
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
  }

   function randomNum() {
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
    return number
  }

  num = randomNum()
  shuffle(arr);

  output.innerHTML += "Convert " + num + ' ' + arr[0] + ' to ' + arr[1]
}

genConversion();
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Random generation was: ', "Convert " + num + ' ' + arr[0] + ' to ' + arr[1]);
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, `arr` is a global variable (not declared inside any function) but num is declared inside `genConversion` hence it exists only there.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your variable above the function as a "let" and then in the function modify the variable. Then call the function. Then you can access the updated value of the variable OUTSIDE the function.

```
let a = null;
const func = () => a = 5;
func();
console.log(a); // 5
```

Comment: I appreciate the response.  This advice did the trick! One issue I also had was that I redeclared the 'num' variable in the function which led to issues.  By declaring 'num' globally and just setting it equal to my randomNum function (within the genConverstion) I was able to access that random number.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want to access a variable outside a function. You're already thinking in functions, so you may benefit from my library, [rubico](https://github.rubico.land). Here's your code in a functional, uni-directional data flow style. Also, use `let` and `const` instead of `var` to avoid unpredictable scope-related behavior.

```js
import { pipe, fork } from 'https://deno.land/x/rubico/rubico.js'
// if you're in the browser, use script type='module' for the import to work

const clearBox = elementID => {
  document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
}

const shuffle = a => { 
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}

const randomNum = () => {
  const number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
  return number
}

const arr = ['mg/mL', 'mcg/mL', 'mg/L']

const randomUnits = () => {
  return shuffle(arr)
}

const addQuestionOutputHTML = question => {
  output.innerHTML += question
  return question
}

// () => string
const generateQuestion = pipe([
  fork({
    num: randomNum, // () => num
    units: randomUnits, // () => shuffledArr
  }), // () => { num, units }
  ({ num, units }) => `Convert ${num}${units[0]} to ${units[1]}`, // { num, units } => string
  addQuestionOutputHTML, // string => string
])

generateQuestion() // => 'Convert 10mg/mL to mcg/mL'
```

I've added some comments to the library specific code, but to really understand and start using rubico for yourself, read this [intuition](https://github.rubico.land#introduction) and then the [docs](https://github.rubico.land#documentation)